# Browsers: Is it possible to to reload font without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

Consider an app that renders something on a canvas. There is the following scenario:
A user loads applications and uses it for some time. He goes to some different views or changes the used font but the font can not be loaded because of no connection issue or timeout. After some time the connection is back and we could load the font for the user.

Is it possible to load the font again? I tried to inject again font-face CSS and wait for the font to be loaded (using [FontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver)) but the browser remembers state when font loading failed.

One more requirement: User can choose from many fonts (around 100) so I do not want to load all of them on initialization - fonts should be loaded on demand.

Comment: It's possible. But share your code.

Comment: Why would you need any code for that? It is about to inject font-face CSS to your app and then let font loading fail (no connection for example). Question is - how to retry to load it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved using Google's Web Font Loader Library, below is the link for reference: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader
Steps to use:

- Include JS file to the library
- Add below code block in JS loader:

```js
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Droid Sans']
    },
    timeout:5000,
    fontactive: function(familyName,fvd){ 
        //This is called once font has been rendered in rowser
        //Your business logic goes here
    },
});
```

Comment: In case I have a lot of fonts (~100) it will be inefficient - all of them will be loaded at the initialization slowing down the app startup. Also, this answer does not solve the question. The same behavior (to wait until font is loaded) is achieved by FontFaceObserver.